# get max ilist item endIng with a number

Tags: c#, ilist

If I have a IList with the following data:

```
{ Price = 220, OtherData = "Zsdd1" }, 
{ Price = 202, OtherData = "Zddsd2" }, 
{ Price = 20, OtherData ="S2A4" }, 
{ Price = 202, OtherData = "ZfdfZ3" }, 
{ Price = 20, OtherData ="SA4" }
```

How can I get the max OtherData, in the case above "SA4" and S2A4" will be the max. I want to return the number 4. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Also, your expected output is ambigous.  Do you expect 4 because you like the number 4, or because its the end of that particular string, or because .... ?  Try to explain what result you are after in terms of process, not in terms of literals.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute LINQ expression, something like this:

```
list.Where(item => char.IsDigit(item.OrderData.Last())).Max(item => item.OrderData.Last());
```